# Identity for sum of squares of reciprocals of binomial numbers

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am  looking for identities for  $$\sum_{k=0}^n  \left(\frac  {k! (n-k)!} {n!}\right)^2.$$  For reciprocal of power one [there are several identities](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL7/Sury/sury99.pdf).

Edit:

Also see [Sury et al paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL7/Sury/sury99.pdf) formula 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following identity is stated in *[Riordan Array Proofs of Identities in Gould’s Book](http://www.dsi.dsi.unifi.it/~resp/GouldBK.pdf)* by R. Sprugnoli in (5.2). It is attributed to Tor B. Staver.

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}^2}=\frac{3(n+1)^2}{2n+3}\cdot\frac{1}{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k}\binom{2k}{k}
> \end{align*}